# Running batch files in sequence

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, batch-file

Does anyone know how to run a series of batch files from a Windows 2008R2 Server from ASP.Net?

I have a \winservice_stop.bat and \winservice_start.bat that I need to run one after the other in my .net application.

Answer (score 0):

Here put all the batch files in sequence into main batch file as main.bat. Then use the below code in asp.net

```
string str_Path = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\main.bat";
        ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(str_Path);
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process batchProcess = new Process();
        batchProcess.StartInfo = processInfo;
        batchProcess.Start();
```